# UnboundLocalError local variable is undefined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
non_punctuation_texts=""
for char in file_contents:
    if char not in punctuations:
        non_punctuation_text=non_punctuation_text+char
words=non_punctuation_text.split()
clean_words=[]
frequencies={}

for word in words:
    if word.isalpha():
        if word not in uninteresting_words:
            clean_words.append(word)
for alpha_word in clean_words:
    if alpha_word not in frequencies:
        frequencies[alpha_word]=1
    else:
        frequencies[alpha_word]+=1
```

im getting the error that my variable is not defined, may someone point out my error and help me wiht a solution?

EXACT ISSUE: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'non_punctuation_text' referenced before assignment

Comment: The error is here: `non_punctuation_text=non_punctuation_text+char`. The variable is never defined before that, so it is impossible to calculate `non_punctuation_text+char`.

Comment: You define a variable `non_punctuation_texts` as an empty string in the first line (with an `s` at the end), but use `non_punctuation_text` (no `s`) in the rest of your code.

Comment: I see the error was the S. Thank you for solving this for me.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by @MattDMo, on line 1 you have

```py
non_punctuation_texts=""
```

Then on line 4 you have

```py
non_punctuation_text=non_punctuation_text+char
```

On line 1 you spell the variable with an `s`, and on line 4 you do not have an `s`. To fix your problem, you need to use the same spelling to reference the same variable.